# Upgrading Bitcoin Core from very old version

Tags: bitcoin-core

Running a full Bitcoin node since 2013 but current version is 0.13.1.
Can I install version 0.20 directly without going through all the intermediate upgrades?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Bitcoin Core is designed so that version 0.20 could be installed directly after 0.13.1. There isn't "going through all the intermediate upgrades" necessary.

Besides, it is even not necessary to uninstall or overwrite 0.13.1. There could be 2 versions installed next to each other. It would probably be safer to configure a separate data directory (blockchain, wallet, config data storage locations or "datadir") to be used by new version.

The best practice is to backup data first before modyfing anything (by default the data are stored in "%UserProfile%\AppData\Roaming\Bitcoin" in Windows).

Comment: Yeah, definitely _do not_ run two installations from one directory. Especially make a backup of the `wallet.dat` before attempting to install the newer version.